# <= today date is pulling future dates as well

Tags: date, google-apps-script

This works almost perfectly but instead of only pulling dates that are today and in the past it pulls future dates well.

```
function checkStatus(objectArray) {
  var resultArray = [];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dashboardSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  //loads the standing today's date from the dashboard sheet, which is stored in cell E10
  var checkDateToday = Utilities.formatDate(dashboardSheet.getRange('E10').getValue(), 'PST', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

  for (var i=0; i<objectArray.length ; i++) {
    var resultObject = objectArray[i];
    var publishDate = Utilities.formatDate(resultObject.publishDate, 'PST', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

  if(( resultObject.qcStatus == "Partner fix" || resultObject.qcStatus == "ordered") && (publishDate <= checkDateToday)){
      resultArray.push(resultObject);
    }

    }
  return resultArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing **strings**, not **dates**.

Consider removing the `Utilities.formatDate` - that is more a tool to "show" dates the way you want - and compare the date objects directly and it will work as expected.

Comment: Removing Utitlities.fomratDate doesn't seem to have affected the outcome --- function checkStatus(objectArray) {
  var checkDateToday = (dashboardSheet.getRange('E10').getValue(), 'PST', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
  
  for (var i=0; i<objectArray.length ; i++) {
    var resultObject = objectArray[i];
    var publishDate = (resultObject.publishDate, 'PST', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
    
  if(( resultObject.qcStatus == "Partner fix" || resultObject.qcStatus == "ordered") && (publishDate <= checkDateToday)){
      resultArray.push(resultObject);
    }

Comment: You misunderstood what I said, I meant remove the whole date formatting on both date elements... just keep `dashboardSheet.getRange('E10').getValue()` and `resultObject.publishDate` as date objects. for info try reading http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp